# How can I install the Google dialer (phone app) on any phone without root?

Tags: google, phone-app

I want Google's Dialer phone app on my Nextbit Robin running Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow but without using root.

Answer (score 0):

Download this APK: http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-phone/google-phone-2-05-07_rc4-release/google-phone-2-05-07_rc4-android-apk-download/

It's an official APK Google released by mistake that does not limit which phone it can be installed on. Unlike the other versions that can only be installed on Nexus phones.

Comment: Fast forward to 2022 (or, 2020), [Phone by Google is now available on the Play Store for non-Nexus/Pixel users](https://9to5google.com/2020/09/08/google-phone-non-pixel-android/)